# wrapping strings around each new line in a rich text box using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, append, richtextbox

I have 2 rich text boxes in my C# Winforms applications called, `richtextbox1` and `richtextbox2` I also have a button called `button1`. The idea is that when the end user pastes in a list of values into `richtextbox1` eg,

```
C1
C2
C3
C4
```

The result of `richtextbox2` should be: (this is what i want help with)

```
IN ('C1','C2','C3', 'C4')
```

This is what I have so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strValues;
    strValues = richTextBox1.Text;
    //MessageBox.Show(strValues);

    string strInStatement;
    strInStatement = richTextBox2.Text;

    List<string> idsList = new List<string>() { strValues };
    string whereClause = string.Join(",", idsList).ToString();

    richTextBox1.Lines = idsList.ToArray();

    foreach (string value in idsList)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: do you want display text in second rich textbox? I think the question is not clear?

Comment: This app is just going to properly form values from `richtextbox1` to create an `IN STATEMENT` for use in SQL

Comment: So yes `richtextbox2` will display the NEW text.

Comment: your problem is can't display `IN ('C1','C2')` like this ah?

Comment: Correct...... I am not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textInEachLine = richTextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string whereClause = string.Join("', '", textInEachLine).ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(" IN ( '" + whereClause + "')");
}
```

This code will remove empty lines if any, and wrap text in each line with single quotes.

Comment: wrong as that is not a valid IN statement. The single quotes are not wrapped around each item?

Comment: I think you will need a foreach statement?

Comment: and you need a comma between each value and the last value must not have a comma.!

Comment: try this again, I have verified it will give you a correct result. `string.Join` will only add separator between values, and not at the last value!

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string whereClause = String.Join("','", richTextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
     richtextbox2.Text = (" IN ( '" + whereClause + "' )");
}
```

Comment: I dont think that will remove the last comma from the array val?

Comment: There is no comma at last.

Comment: I will up vote you as other user got in with the answer before you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


    string whereClause = String.Join("','", richTextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None));


        MessageBox.Show(" IN ( '" + whereClause + "')");

        }
```

Comment: You are missing the single quotes around each new line?